# Remove invalid request parameter from URL with servlet filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a web application written in Java which uses Struts 1.0. Sometimes when a URL is fired, I can see that it one of the request parameters does not have any name and value like the following ...

```
http://www.aaa.com/test.do?a=1&b=2&=&d=4&e=5
```

As can be seen, there is a '&=' which is essentially a parameter with no name and value. I'd like to remove this part from the URL before sending the request to the server. How can I achieve this? Should I use a filter or is there an easier way?

Comment: At the risk of seeming flippant, why do you care?  Good practice is generally to ignore parameters you don't expect and only read the ones you do.  Why spend time processing something you could just ignore?

Comment: I currently run my application on JBoss 7.1.1 and when I access it using IE9+, I get a 'Parameters failed processing' error in the browser due to the afore mentioned problem. This is apparently a known issue in JBoss 7.1.1 and so I need a work around for it.

Comment: Struts 1.0? Why oh why? Even Struts 1.3.x is discontinued.

Comment: The fact that the application is still on struts 1.0 is out of my control. If you have a solution for my problem, please let me know